# get the option value of multiple dropdown having same class in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have added the  multiple dropdown list having same class name select_drop and there is one dropdown list using different class name drop.I want to apply condition if its match the  two dropdown option then alert same column cant choose at the  same time.for example:- If i choose option  firstname from first dropdown and choose a option firstname from third dropdown then it give alert which is working in my code.But there is a problem occurs if i choose the lastname option from second dropdown and choose the option lastname from third dropdown it does not work.The problem is that it only match the first dropdown option not other options.I want if someone chooses option for third dropdown which having different class and he choose the option name firstname or lastname which is already selected in above two dropdown then it will give alert same column cant be choose.User cant choose same column or selected column again in the third dropdown which have different class.If he choose then it will give alert.

```
<select class="select_drop" id="select_drop">
    <option value="firstname">firstname</option>
    <option  value="lastname">lastname</option>
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="gender">gender</option>

</select>
<br>
<select class="select_drop" id="select_drop">
    <option value="firstname">firstname</option>
    <option  value="lastname">lastname</option>
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="gender">gender</option>

</select>
<br>
<select class="drop" id="drop">
    <option value="firstname">firstname</option>
    <option  value="lastname">lastname</option>
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="gender">gender</option>

</select>
<script>
$(function () {
        $("#drop").change(function () {
            var selectedText = $(this).val();

          var v = $('#select_drop').find("option:selected").text();

            if(selectedText == v){
              alert('same column name cant be choose');
              location.reload();
            }
           alert(v + selectedText);
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggesstion is, you need to check each dropdown and also you need to remove ids from first two dropdown. Here is my code(sorry for syntax errors and typo if any, because i am on phone right now):

```
<script> 
    $(function () { 
        $("#drop").change(function () { 
            var selectedText = $(this).val();
            var v = [];
            $(".select_drop").each(function(){
                v.push($(this).val());
            })     
            if($.inArray(selectedText, v) >= 0){ 
                 alert('your alert'); 
                 location.reload(); 
            } 

         })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: please limit your answer into one :D

Comment: sorry, i am using Stack Exchange app first time. i will delete other answer :)

Comment: @babi if your dropdown is in a loop, using each will be best for you.

Comment: @tanha_emin I have used your code it works.Thankyou so much for help me.

Comment: Glad to help @babi :) can you check as answer :)

Comment: it is glad for me, have a nice day :)

Comment: as a developer, we need to think more than description, definition or acceptance and also my answer is for original post too :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you cannot have the same element ID in your DOM.
Assign different ID for 1st and 2nd dropdown.

```
<select class="select_drop" id="select_drop_1">
    <option value="firstname">firstname</option>
    <option  value="lastname">lastname</option>
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="gender">gender</option>

</select>
<br>
<select class="select_drop" id="select_drop_2">
    <option value="firstname">firstname</option>
    <option  value="lastname">lastname</option>
    <option value="email">email</option>
    <option value="gender">gender</option>

</select>
```

Then in your event listener check the two dropdowns.

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $("#drop").change(function () {
            var selectedText = $(this).val();

            var first_drop = $('#select_drop_1').val(); // Get selected value of first dropdown
            var second_drop = $('#select_drop_2').val(); // Get selected value of second dropdown

            if(selectedText == first_drop || selectedText == second_drop){ // Check if either of the first and second have the same value with the third
              alert('same column name cant be choose');
              location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

I added a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/so5a3k67/

Comment: It Works.But if dropdown is in for loop then how can i add different ids.

Comment: Is this php? you can add an iterator and append that to your dropdown ID

Comment: yes this code i want to use  for php .I have created dropdown list using for loop in php